# code doesn't compile at Compact Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, delegates, compact-framework, compact-framework2.0

The following code doesn't compile on Compact Framework 2 ( VS2008 )

```
public delegate TResult Func<out TResult>();
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T a);
public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, in T3, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3);
public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, in T3, in T4, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4);
```

I'm not sure about what the code author meant to do, and I need to know how to workaroudn that.

Aditional Info:
This code came from [LinqBridge](https://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/downloads/detail?name=LinqBridge-1.3.cs)'s source

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is just defining various `Func` delegates that weren't yet defined in .NET 2.0,

Try taking out the `in` and `out` modifiers, since they aren't supported in .NET 2.0 either:

```
public delegate TResult Func<TResult>();
public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T a);
public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3);
public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4);
```

Comment: Hi, Stanley. Do you know the consequences of taking those modifiers off?

Comment: In .NET 4.0 and later the interfaces would not be [covariant or contravariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.100).aspx).